# Mem and Swap from the top command output

Tags: linux, caching, buffer, swap

I checked the memory usage from a node of our cluster. a snapshot of the `top`command is as following:

```
Mem:  24659948k total,  3113860k used, 21546088k free,   168328k buffers
Swap: 28667984k total,   570196k used, 28097788k free,   353460k cached
```

I have a few questions with regard to the output above.

1. The node has plenty of free physical memory. Then why is there some swap space used?
2. The physical memory has `168328k buffers`. what is it? What is it used for?
3. Same question to the `cached` swap. What is it? What is it used for?
4. Is there any performance implication about the cluster node from the above output?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap space used is determined by your 'swappiness' system value.
To find your current setting, try:
`cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
The value can range from 0-100, with 100 being agressive swapping, and 0 meaning swap is only used when your RAM is at capacity.
To adjust the value temporarily, try:
`echo $YOURVALUE > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
and to adjust it permanently, add a sysctl option
`echo $YOURVALUE >> /etc/sysctl.conf; sysctl -p`

Buffers and cache are for commonly opened and executed commands. Don't worry about them as space being "used", the kernel will automatically free up that space if the RAM is needed. You can force clear the cache with the following command (though it's really not needed):
`sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`